# Javascript - Create monitoring graphs with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I need to create 3 types of monitoring graphs (basic column, line with data labels and 3D donut) based on a CSV file as part of a proof of concept.
Here is a part of my CSV file :

Job ID,Job name,Job status ID,Job status,Start time,End time,Something,Error
28681,"JX_ODS_INT_DWH_D_RAM_OCC_MOTIF",2,"WAR","2013-04-29-01.15.34.000000","2013-04-29-01.15.47.000000",,""
28701,"JX_ODS_INT_DWH_D_SCN_EVENEMENT",2,"WAR","2013-04-29-01.16.25.000000","2013-04-29-01.16.36.000000",,""
28721,"JX_ODS_INT_DWH_D_SCN_MOTIF",2,"WAR","2013-04-29-01.16.43.000000","2013-04-29-01.16.53.000000",,""
28741,"JX_ODS_INT_DWH_D_SCN_SOURCE",2,"WAR","2013-04-29-01.17.01.000000","2013-04-29-01.17.11.000000",,""
28761,"JX_ODS_INT_DWH_D_SCN_TYPE",2,"WAR","2013-04-29-01.17.19.000000","2013-04-29-01.17.59.000000",,""
28781,"JX_ODS_INT_DWH_D_COL_MOTIF_B2C_LIVR_INST",2,"WAR","2013-04-29-01.18.05.000000","2013-04-29-01.18.15.000000",,""
28801,"JX_ODS_INT_DWH_D_GEO_COT",2,"WAR","2013-04-29-01.18.23.000000","2013-04-29-01.18.33.000000",,""
28821,"JX_FILE_INT_DWH_D_CLI_RATACHEMENT",1,"OK","2013-04-29-01.18.39.000000","2013-04-29-01.18.51.000000",,""

With these data I need to display the number of jobs who are in status "OK", "KO", "WAR" and "En cours..." in a given period (with the start time).
And with the examples on the Highcharts website, I didn't find how to parse correctly my CSV file to have the graphs that I want.

If you have any ideas I'm very interested ! ;)

Update 1 :

To be more specific, I would want to count the number of rows in my CSV file, categorize it with the status "OK", "KO", "WAR" and "En cours..." and spread the results in charts with the date in analysis axis.
Is that possible with Highcharts or must I do it with something else?

Comment: Okay, but what exactly you don't know/understand? Sorry, but what have you tried? In the Highcahrts demo pages, you can find a couple of example for parsing your own CSV data, or using `data` module. The second one may not exactly fit your needs but in the source code you can find some of the ideas.

Comment: I understand the data module of Highcharts, but i don't know how to use it with the data contained in my CSV file.

Comment: And for the examples, they use very simple CSVs...

Comment: You're looking to aggregate your data, whereas the data module in highcharts is more geared toward ready to use data.  There are a ton of ways to go about parsing CSV data - if that's your question, I would update your post to be more specific.